# Display manager SDDM doesn't make use of 3rd monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm, display-manager, sddm

I have computer with 2 videocards and 3 monitors attached - 2 to one card and 1 to another one. I run Ubuntu Server with X and I want to use most lightweight display manager as possible. I’m trying to use SDDM but I faced a problem that after boot my system has desktop using only 2 monitors attached to one card and the 3rd monitor is unavailable to it.

I’ve installed and run LightDM with absolutely the same system configuration and after boot with this manager my system has desktop utilizing all 3 monitors.

Is it possible to configure SDDM to work with 3 monitors in my case or this is limitation of SDDM by design?

Here is some information on system running SDDM and LightDM:

1. `Xrandr –listproviders` are absolutely the same:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x55 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:Unknown AMD Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:08:00.0
Provider 1: id: 0x93 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

2. `Xrandr –query` has one difference in `DVI-D-1-2` section:

*LightDM*

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2293 x 3240, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected 1920x1080+373+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
…
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
…
DVI-D-1-2 connected 1920x1080+143+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93  
…
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
…
```

*SDDM*

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2293 x 3240, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected 1920x1080+373+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
…
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
…
DVI-D-1-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93  
…
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
…
```

3. `Xrandr –listmonitors` differs correspondingly:

*LightDM*

```
0: +*DVI-D-0 1920/477x1080/268+0+1080  DVI-D-0
 1: +HDMI-A-0 1920/477x1080/268+373+2160  HDMI-A-0
 2: +DVI-D-1-2 1920/598x1080/336+143+0  DVI-D-1-2
```

*SDDM*

```
0: +*DVI-D-0 1920/477x1080/268+0+1080  DVI-D-0
 1: +HDMI-A-0 1920/477x1080/268+373+2160  HDMI-A-0
```

4. `Inxi -Gx` shows some fail for SDDM:

*LightDM*

```
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] vendor: Gigabyte driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Device-2: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 08:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu,ati,modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-91-generic LLVM 11.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes
```

*SDDM*

```
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] vendor: Gigabyte driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Device-2: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 08:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu,modesetting FAILED: ati unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-91-generic LLVM 11.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes
```

System info:

```
uname -a
hostname 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

---

**UPDATE**

Just to remove potential problem upgraded using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` with no effect.

Comment: Why haven't you been applying upgrades?  Your `lsb_release` detail implies you've not applied updates in months (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date).  Are you using Ubuntu? or a system based on Ubuntu?

Comment: This is Ubuntu. I didn't apply upgrades due to some kind of limitation on using another release.

Comment: To apply upgrades you  have to run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` ...

Comment: @SorenA Done exactly as you recommended but nothing changed, clarified this in update section of the question.